# How to make nested JSON result from MySQL query in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have 2 MySQL tables,let's call it `kj` which is the parent of `jj` as the children table. Currently, I have the SQL query written in my NodeJS code to return this output:

```js
[{
    "id_kj": 1,
    "title_kj": "title1",
    "description_kj": "description1",
    "image_kj": "image1",
    "id_jj": 66,
    "title_jj": "title1",
    "description_jj": "description1",
    "image_jj": "image1"
  },
  {
    "id_kj": 1,
    "title_kj": "title1",
    "description_kj": "description1",
    "image_kj": "image1",
    "id_jj": 67,
    "title_jj": "title1",
    "description_jj": "description1",
    "image_jj": "image1"
  },
  {
    "id_kj": 1,
    "title_kj": "title1",
    "description_kj": "description1",
    "image_kj": "image1",
    "id_jj": 68,
    "title_jj": "title1",
    "description_jj": "description1",
    "image_jj": "image1"
  },
  {
    "id_kj": 2,
    "title_kj": "title2",
    "description_kj": "description2",
    "image_kj": "image2",
    "id_jj": 71,
    "title_jj": "title1",
    "description_jj": "description2",
    "image_jj": "image2"
  },
  {
    "id_kj": 2,
    "title_kj": "title2",
    "description_kj": "description2",
    "image_kj": "image2",
    "id_jj": 69,
    "title_jj": "title1",
    "description_jj": "description2",
    "image_jj": "image2"
  },
  {
    "id_kj": 2,
    "title_kj": "title2",
    "description_kj": "description2",
    "image_kj": "image2",
    "id_jj": 70,
    "title_jj": "title1",
    "description_jj": "description2",
    "image_jj": "image2"
  },
  {
    "id_kj": 3,
    "title_kj": "title3",
    "description_kj": "description3",
    "image_kj": "image3",
    "id_jj": 72,
    "title_jj": "title3",
    "description_jj": "description3",
    "image_jj": "image3"
  },
  {
    "id_kj": 3,
    "title_kj": "title3",
    "description_kj": "description3",
    "image_kj": "image3",
    "id_jj": 73,
    "title_jj": "title3",
    "description_jj": "description3",
    "image_jj": "image3"
  },
  {
    "id_kj": 3,
    "title_kj": "title3",
    "description_kj": "description3",
    "image_kj": "image3",
    "id_jj": 74,
    "title_jj": "title3",
    "description_jj": "description3",
    "image_jj": "image3"
  }
]
```

How do I make the result nested? I need `id_jj, title_jj, description_jj, image_jj` to be the children of each `id_kj` key. Here are the result I need it to be:

```js
[{
    "id_kj": 1,
    "title_kj": "title1",
    "description_kj": "description1",
    "image_kj": "image1",
    "children": [{
        "id_jj": 66,
        "title_jj": "title1",
        "description_jj": "description1",
        "image_jj": "image1"
      },
      {
        "id_jj": 67,
        "title_jj": "title1",
        "description_jj": "description1",
        "image_jj": "image1"
      },
      {
        "id_jj": 68,
        "title_jj": "title1",
        "description_jj": "description1",
        "image_jj": "image1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id_kj": 2,
    "title_kj": "title2",
    "description_kj": "description2",
    "image_kj": "image2",
    "children": [{
        "id_jj": 71,
        "title_jj": "title1",
        "description_jj": "description2",
        "image_jj": "image2"
      },
      {
        "id_jj": 69,
        "title_jj": "title1",
        "description_jj": "description2",
        "image_jj": "image2"
      },
      {
        "id_jj": 70,
        "title_jj": "title1",
        "description_jj": "description2",
        "image_jj": "image2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id_kj": 3,
    "title_kj": "title3",
    "description_kj": "description3",
    "image_kj": "image3",
    "children": [{
        "id_jj": 72,
        "title_jj": "title3",
        "description_jj": "description3",
        "image_jj": "image3"
      },
      {
        "id_jj": 73,
        "title_jj": "title3",
        "description_jj": "description3",
        "image_jj": "image3"
      },
      {
        "id_jj": 74,
        "title_jj": "title3",
        "description_jj": "description3",
        "image_jj": "image3"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And here's my code:

```js
const getData = async function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    const query = "SELECT a.`id` AS 'id_kj', a.`title` AS 'title_kj', a.`description` AS 'description_kj', a.`image` AS 'image_kj',\n" +
      "b.`id` AS 'id_jj', b.`title` AS 'title_jj', b.`description` AS 'description_jj', b.`image` AS 'image_jj' FROM `kj` AS a LEFT JOIN `jj` AS b\n" +
      "ON a.`id` = b.`id_kj` GROUP BY a.`id`, b.`id` ORDER BY  a.`title` ASC, b.`title` DESC";
    con.query(query, function(error, results) {
      if (results.length > 0) {
        resolve(results);
      } else {
        resolve(null);
      }
    });
  });
};

module.exports = {
  getNestedData: async function(baseResponse) {
    const data = await getPelatihan();
    return data;
  },
};
```

I've also created the SQL Fiddle scheme of my tables, here's the fiddle link:
[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eBQ99qxfkSYKdPoYjdMEMF/2)

Any help will be much appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option that should be pretty efficient and logically relatively simple will be to perform the join in memory.

We create a map of the result_kj table by the joining field title_kj, then iterate over the result_jj table to populate the result_kj children.

```js
let result_kj = [{ "id_kj": 1, "title_kj": "title2", "description_kj": "description1", "image_kj": "image1", "id_jj": 66, "title_jj": "title2", "description_jj": "description1", "image_jj": "image1" }, { "id_kj": 1, "title_kj": "title2", "description_kj": "description1", "image_kj": "image1", "id_jj": 67, "title_jj": "title2", "description_jj": "description1", "image_jj": "image1" }, { "id_kj": 1, "title_kj": "title1", "description_kj": "description1", "image_kj": "image1", "id_jj": 68, "title_jj": "title1", "description_jj": "description1", "image_jj": "image1" }, { "id_kj": 2, "title_kj": "title2", "description_kj": "description2", "image_kj": "image2", "id_jj": 71, "title_jj": "title1", "description_jj": "description2", "image_jj": "image2" }, { "id_kj": 2, "title_kj": "title2", "description_kj": "description2", "image_kj": "image2", "id_jj": 69, "title_jj": "title1", "description_jj": "description2", "image_jj": "image2" }, { "id_kj": 2, "title_kj": "title2", "description_kj": "description2", "image_kj": "image2", "id_jj": 70, "title_jj": "title1", "description_jj": "description2", "image_jj": "image2" }, { "id_kj": 3, "title_kj": "title3", "description_kj": "description3", "image_kj": "image3", "id_jj": 72, "title_jj": "title3", "description_jj": "description3", "image_jj": "image3" }, { "id_kj": 3, "title_kj": "title3", "description_kj": "description3", "image_kj": "image3", "id_jj": 73, "title_jj": "title3", "description_jj": "description3", "image_jj": "image3" }, { "id_kj": 3, "title_kj": "title3", "description_kj": "description3", "image_kj": "image3", "id_jj": 74, "title_jj": "title3", "description_jj": "description3", "image_jj": "image3" } ]; 
let result_jj = [{ "id_jj": 66, "title_jj": "title1", "description_jj": "description1", "image_jj": "image1" }, { "id_jj": 67, "title_jj": "title1", "description_jj": "description1", "image_jj": "image1" }, { "id_jj": 68, "title_jj": "title1", "description_jj": "description1", "image_jj": "image1" }, { "id_jj": 71, "title_jj": "title2", "description_jj": "description2", "image_jj": "image2" }, { "id_jj": 69, "title_jj": "title2", "description_jj": "description2", "image_jj": "image2" }, { "id_jj": 70, "title_jj": "title2", "description_jj": "description2", "image_jj": "image2" }, { "id_jj": 72, "title_jj": "title3", "description_jj": "description3", "image_jj": "image3" }, { "id_jj": 73, "title_jj": "title3", "description_jj": "description3", "image_jj": "image3" }, { "id_jj": 74, "title_jj": "title3", "description_jj": "description3", "image_jj": "image3" } ]; 
   
// Sort by the relevant key
const sortKey = "title_kj";
result_kj.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a[sortKey] < b[sortKey]) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (a[sortKey] > b[sortKey]) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
})

let kjMap = result_kj.reduce((map, row) => {
    key = row["title_kj"]; 
    map[key] = row;
    return map;
}, {})

let resultMap = result_jj.reduce((map, row) => { 
    let key = row["title_jj"];
    if (map[key]) { 
        if (!map[key].children) map[key].children = [];
        map[key].children.push(row);
    }
    return map;
}, kjMap)

let result = Object.values(resultMap);
console.log("Result:", result);
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. Correct me if I'm wrong, in order to generate `result_kj` and `result_jj` I need to have 2 queries?

Comment: Hi @MAnsyori you do absolutely! However, the 2 queries may well be less resource intensive than one complex join query. There won't be a massive difference in any case.

Comment: Woah it works! thanks. I have one more question if you don't mind. How do I arrange the parent result to be sorted in alphabetical order? the `jj` result map is already ordered as it is. Using ORDER BY `title` ASC in parent query didn't work.

Comment: We could do a sort in memory if we wanted to, though it should work in SQL land too. I'll add an example of sorting in memory just for completeness!

Comment: The reason why the parent is not sorted is that I change the "key" in parent to `id_kj` and changed the children "key" to `id_kj`, and the default sorting is based on `id_kj`. In this case, I ended up adding a new function and sort in memory just like you said, and now everything is complete! thanks again. cheers.

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help, happy coding!